# Joi validation of array

Tags: hapi.js, joi

trying to validate that an array has zero or more strings in one case and that it has zero or more objects in another , struggling with Joi docs :(

```js
validate: {
    headers: Joi.object({
            'content-type': "application/vnd.api+json",
            accept: "application/vnd.api+json"
    }).options({ allowUnknown: true }),
    payload : Joi.object().keys({
        data : Joi.object().keys({
            type: Joi.any().allow('BY_TEMPLATE').required(),
            attributes: Joi.object({
                to : Joi.string().email().required(),
                templateId : Joi.string().required(),
                categories : Joi.array().items( //trying to validate here that each element is a string),
                variables : Joi.array({
                    //also trying to validate here that each element is an Object with one key and value
                })
            })
        }).required()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 262, accepted):

`Joi.array().items()` accepts another Joi schema to use against the array elements.  So an array of strings is this easy:

```
Joi.array().items(Joi.string())
```

Same for an array of objects; just pass an object schema to `items()`:

```
Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
    // Object schema
}))
```

Comment: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
    inputA:Joi.string().optional(), inputB:Joi.string().require()
}))  on these schema  inputA is optional and inputB is required but when send the req inputA giving in validated error inputA should not blank

Comment: @MohammadFaisal I cannot reproduce that error. With that schema, the value `[{ inputB: 'test' }]` passes validation. Double-check your code. Note that `[{ inputA: '', inputB: 'test' }]` does _not_ pass validation -- either pass a non-empty string, or don't pass anything. (A string is required to have at least one character by default, _if it is provided._ So just don't send empty strings!)

Answer (score 33):

If you want to validate an array of strings in Joi:

`Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"))`

Answer (score 18):

you can try this:

```js
function(data) {
 const Schema = {
   categories: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()),
   variables: Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys().min(1))
 }
 return Joi.validate(data, Schema)
}
```

for more details checkout this repo:  https://github.com/raysk4ever/nodejs_withMongoRefArray

Comment: please provide some explanation, so that all will benefit from your answer.

Comment: @Zeina checkout this https://github.com/raysk4ever/nodejs_withMongoRefArray

Comment: This worked in my case as I was just testing an solution. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 11):

You can also try this way, I have been using it for long time and working fine for me.

If your array is array of objects than use below:

```js
const Joi = require('joi');

let schema = Joi.object().keys({
    items: Joi.array().items(
        Joi.object({
            item_id: Joi.number().required(),
            item_qty: Joi.number().required(),
            item_type_id: Joi.number().required(),
            item_qty: Joi.number().required(),
            base_price: Joi.number().required(),
            actual_price: Joi.number().required(),
        })
    ).required(),
});

let errors = Joi.validate(req.body, schema);
```

if you array is simple array than:

```js
let schema = Joi.object().keys({
    items: Joi.array().items(
    Joi.number().required()
).min(10).required()});
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me accomplish what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

`Joi.array().items(Joi.string().required(), Joi.number().required());` found it [here](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#arrayitemstype)

Answer (score 4):

Validation when we have an array of objects using Joi:

```
const schema = Joi.array().items(
Joi.object().keys({
  id: Joi.number().required(),
  name: Joi.string().required(),
}));
```

We could add validations for objects inside an array itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
validate: {
        headers: Joi.object({
                'content-type': "application/vnd.api+json",
                accept: "application/vnd.api+json"
        }).options({ allowUnknown: true }),
        payload : Joi.object().keys({
            data : Joi.object().keys({
                type: Joi.any().allow('BY_TEMPLATE').required(),
                attributes: Joi.object({
                    to : Joi.string().email().required(),
                    templateId : Joi.string().required(),
                    categories : Joi.array().items(Joi.string()),
                    variables : Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys().max(1))
                })
            }).required()
        })
    }
```