# Joi validation - How to validate an array of objects where only one object is required and the other is not

Tags: node.js, validation, hapi.js, joi

I want to validate an array that contains several objects using Joi. Although I cannot find a way to mark one of the objects in the array list as "required = false".

Is there a way to accomplish this with Joi?

Comment: Use .required(true) on the object that is required, the other one will be optional by default.

Comment: Could you please give little detail about your data, what kind of array of elements do you have?

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
   // Object schema
}))
```

[Ref link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42656623/8612835)

[Ref link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37746388/8612835)

Comment: what if one of the objects matches, I want to ignore the other schema and move to the next data from an array? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74658952/joi-validations-if-object-matches-the-schema-validate-against-it-from-multiple

Comment: @Bravo I don't think so that can be possible till I know.

Comment: Thanks @Sachin Is there any other way I can achieve that functionality ?

Comment: Yes of course @Bravo you can implement through your business logic. i.e you can loop with your JSON data and make joi payload, once any object matches you can skip rest of the data in loop and go ahead.

Comment: Thanks. If you have any examples can you please share with me as I am totally new to this.